# Optimal string from segments with words and timestamps

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, alignment, transcription

I have a list of segments of transcribed audio. These transcriptions have words with timestamps and confidence. For example:

```
 Goedemiddag, 1.13 1.54 0.94892578125
 welkom       1.68 1.98 0.9658203125
 bij          1.98 2.16 0.99853515625
 de           2.16 2.3  0.98291015625
 middag       2.3 2.84  0.858154296875
 show         2.84 3.58 0.81549072265625
 Ik           3.92 4.06 0.99365234375
```

And the next:

```
 Welkom       1.52 1.96 0.856689453125
 bij          1.96 2.12 0.99853515625
 de           2.12 2.3  0.9833984375
 middag       2.3 2.84  0.843994140625
 show         2.84 3.56 0.812255859375
 Ik           3.94 4.06 0.99267578125
 ben          4.06 4.24 0.9990234375
```

Etc.

There is some overlap (currently 4 seconds overlap for each 5 second transcription, but that will be less later on)

Is there a general algorithm that merges these sequences to one big optimal sequence*? By optimal I mean by taking into account the word-level confidence.
In this case, the words are transcribed the same, but the transciber might have made a mistake, i.e. a word can be mis-transcribed so there doesn't need to be an exact string match.

[*] I looked into bio-informatics optimal sequence alignment algorithm, but that does not take into account the timestamp/position information that I already have, so it seems there must be an optimization possibility.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "optimal". Readers will of course need a precise definition of that term to be able to help you. That is, they will need something common to all optimization problems: a function that maps the data to a number that is to be minimized or maximized. Could you also provide an optimal solution for your example and explain why it is superior to other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know an obvious algorithm to solve this problem, but I think, maybe following proposal will be useful:

1. You will create a `vote` structure, contains pair (letter, confidence).
2. You will create 2d array of such structures, where is:

- X is a "timeslot", in your case - 10ms timeslot position, like 1.13, 1.14, etc.
- Y is a channel. In your example, you have 2 overlapped channels.

Thereafter, for each your chunk, you compute array position for each letter, and apply into vote[time][chan] a pair, generated from your chunk.
When appying ends, you will scan an array by timeslots, and for each slot you select a latter with maximal vote level.